# How can I insert a space character in every upper case letter expect the first one at each element of string array in DXL script?

Tags: ibm-doors

I would like to edit the elements of string array with DXL script which is used in for loop. The problem will be described in the following:
I would like to insert space in front of every upper case letter expect the first one and it would be applied for all lines in string array.

Example:

There is a string array:

AbcDefGhi

GhiDefAbc

DefGhiAbc

etc.

and finally I would like to see the result as:

Abc Def Ghi

Ghi Def Abc

Def Ghi Abc

etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Derived straightly from the DXL manual..

```
Regexp upperChar  = regexp2 "[A-Z]"
string s = "yoHelloUrban"

string sNew = ""
while (upperChar s) {
   sNew = sNew s[ 0 : (start 0) - 1] " " s [match 0]
   s = s[end 0 + 1:]
}
sNew = sNew s
print sNew
```

You might have to tweak around the fact that you do not want EVERY capital letter to be replaced with  , only those that are not at the beginning of your string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution written as a function that you can just drop into your code. It processes an input string character by character. Always outputs the first character as-is, then inserts a space before any subsequent upper-case character.

For efficiency, if processing a large number of strings, or very large strings (or both!), the function could be modified to append to a buffer instead of a string, before finally returning a string.

```
string spaceOut(string sInput)
{
    const int intA = 65 // DECIMAL 65 = ASCII 'A'
    const int intZ = 90 // DECIMAL 90 = ASCII 'Z'

    int intStrLength = length(sInput)
    int iCharCounter = 0

    string sReturn = ""

    sReturn = sReturn sInput[0] ""

    for (iCharCounter = 1; iCharCounter < intStrLength; iCharCounter++)
    {
        if ((intOf(sInput[iCharCounter]) >= intA)&&(intOf(sInput[iCharCounter]) <= intZ))
        {
            sReturn = sReturn " " sInput[iCharCounter] ""
        }
        else
        {
            sReturn = sReturn sInput[iCharCounter] ""
        }
    }

    return(sReturn)
}

print(spaceOut("AbcDefGHi"))
```